# Convert array of hashes to json

Tags: perl

I want to convert an array of hashes that I create like this:

```
while(...)
{
    ...
    push(@ranks, {id => $id, time => $time});
}
```

To JSON:

```
use JSON;
$j = new JSON;
print $j->encode_json({ranks => @ranks});
```

But it is outputting this:

```
{"ranks":{"time":"3","id":"tiago"},
 "HASH(0x905bf70)":{"time":"10","id":"bla"}}
```

As you can see it isnt able to write on of the hashes and there's no array...

I would like to output a JSON string that looked like this:

```
 {"ranks":[{"time":"3","id":"tiago"},
           {"time":"40","id":"fhddhf"},
           {"time":"10","id":"bla"}]}
```

Comment: What is $j?  What package are you using for JSON support?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print $j->encode_json({ranks => @ranks});
```

should be:

```
print $j->encode_json({ranks => \@ranks});
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Can you explain the difference?

Comment: without the reference, the array will be interpolated into its individual elements....

Comment: ...the first of which is taken as the value for the ranks key, and the remainder of which are taken as additional (stringified) keys and values

Answer (score 7):

All of these are the same:

```
ranks => @ranks

'ranks', @ranks

'ranks', $ranks[0], $ranks[1], $ranks[2]

ranks => $ranks[0], $ranks[1] => $ranks[2]
```

So you're creating a hash with two elements when you mean to create a hash with one element.

You tried to use an array as a hash value, but hash values can only be scalars. It is common, however, to use a reference to an array as a hash value since references are scalars, and this is what `encode_json` expects.

```
print $j->encode_json( { ranks => @ranks } );
```

should be

```
print $j->encode_json( { ranks => \@ranks } );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try passing the array as a reference.

`to_json({ranks => \@ranks},{ascii => 1,pretty => 1});`