# Return a JSON object from Perl

Tags: perl

I am not very familiar with Pearl so please forgive my facepalm of a question.
I'm trying & failing miserably to return a `JSON` object from a subroutine.

I have created a `.pl` file that makes a query and returns some data. Great - I can get a response and here is what my data looks like that is returning that object:

```
# Print JSON
print encode_json({
    'status' => scalar(@$payload) > 0 ? 200 : 404,
    'message' => scalar(@$payload) > 0 ? 'OK' : 'Not found.',
    'data' => scalar(@$payload) > 0 ? $payload : []
});

// $payload = mySubRoutine({...});
```

The actual response looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        "foo",
        8
    ]
}
```

Which *technically* works, but just feels super gross getting to the data using `data[1]`.

From my `sub` I am returning the data like this (resulting in the above):

```
...
$my foo = 8;
return (["foo" => $foo]);
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {"foo":8}
    ]
}
```

I have tried to export a `JSON` object like this (and works):

```
my $json = JSON::XS::encode_json({foo => $foo});
die Data::Dumper::Dumper($json);  // $VAR1 = '{"foo":8}';
```

Great - getting closer, now I just need to return that from my subroutine instead of dumping it out:

```
my $json = JSON::XS::encode_json({foo => $foo});
return $json;
```

However, doing that gives me this error:

> Can't use string ("{"foo":8}") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Now I'm talking myself in circles to return the data from my subroutine in an acceptable format. I've also looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095410/convert-array-of-hashes-to-json) to return `JSON`. I still am left with some version of the above error.

Any suggestions on the correct syntax would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a matter of formatting your data structure the way you want, not really JSON which just creates a representation of how you've structured it.

Hashes in Perl map to JSON objects. You can create a hash out of a list ordered in alternating key-value pairs, indeed in the same way you create the overall structure to pass to `encode_json`.

Say if your subroutine returned a hashref instead of an arrayref as the `$payload`:

```
return {foo => $foo};
```

And have it return `undef` rather than an empty structure to indicate not found, this is a clearer indication and can be tested with `defined` or the `//` (defined-or) operator.

Then you could set that as the value and it would be encoded to a JSON object:

```
encode_json({
    'status' => defined($payload) ? 200 : 404,
    'message' => defined($payload) ? 'OK' : 'Not found.',
    'data' => $payload // {},
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had figured. Complete syntax problem due to flat lack of figuring out what was getting returned where/how. I've updated my script to return a better structure then used your suggestion. Home run - thank you very much for your time!